# Adding white border to SKSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm trying to add a temporary white border to a sprite. To achieve this, I'm building another sprite with the same texture but slightly bigger than the first. I then set its color to white and draw this new sprite behind its parent, fade it out and finally remove it. Here's my code:

```
func blink() {
     if let currentTexture = self.texture {
        let biggerSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: currentTexture)
        biggerSprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        biggerSprite.color = SKColor.white
        biggerSprite.xScale *= 1.3
        biggerSprite.yScale *= 1.3
        biggerSprite.position = CGPoint.zero
        biggerSprite.name = "aura"
        biggerSprite.zPosition = zPositions.background
        addChild(biggerSprite)
        let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 3)
        let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        biggerSprite.run(SKAction.sequence([fadeOut, remove]))
    }
}
```

It works and I can see the border fading out but the problem is: "biggerSprite" doesn't get coloured with white as I wanted/expected. I'm guessing setting the color implies a multiplication with the existing texture's colours. How can I fill my "background"/border sprite with a solid white colour?

Answer (score 2):

coloring a sprite white is the same as removing color from it. you cannot take a multi colored sprite and saturate it by coloring it white. You have to make your background image white or light to start with.

If you had a sprite texture and you applied a red color to it and it had a colorBlendFactor of 1 the image would just become shaded red now, with darker portions of the original image just being darker shades of red. Applying a white color to this image now would reset it back to it's original color state.

[image]

[image]